# Text Mining - Similarity among words to determine thresholds

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining

While trying to find how one place (Military High School) like a school is similar to another one (Military H School or Military High S), I used the LV algorithm to find the string distance and then converted them into a percentage on a calibrated scale.

```
stringdist(data[i,1],data[i,2],method = "lv")
```

Though this is admissible, I still need a more precise way to determine the threshold. Any suggestions.

Comment: It is my sense that you may want to state what your goal is, as I suspect your threshold will likely depend on what you are trying to achieve.  The following SO post is NOT likely a duplicate but may be helpful [How can I create a threshold for similar strings using Levenshtein distance and account for typos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340551/how-can-i-create-a-threshold-for-similar-strings-using-levenshtein-distance-and)

Comment: Thanks for the similar question. The goal is to set a threshold of acceptance for a variation of a name from the standardized name, so that say if the threshold of this word is less than say 85%, it would be rejected. This exercise is part of data pre-processing.

Comment: I am thinking now that you may want to include other tags indicating that this is a data science questions (the 'text-mining' tag may be enough) and/or put it up on the Data Science Stack Exchange site as this is not so much about "R" (but sort of is).

Comment: (For others, 'lv' is apparently R's idea of how you abbreviate "Levenshtein") Is edit distance really what you want here? Isn't "H.S." a *much* better match for "High School" than "Night School," despite the edit distances? Perhaps you want to take a step back and consider how synonyms and alternative words/spellings play into your distance metric.

Comment: Yes a lookup table of such synonyms may help but the variations are too many to capture as it is just not the schools but academies, colleges, etc.